# How to make a loop iterate 60 times a second?

Tags: c#, loops, dotnet-httpclient

I'm querying an API which has a limit to the number of queries you can do a second. For example, you might be allowed to make 20 queries a second. If you over query the server you get a 429 error which prevents you from accessing the API.

The issue come with a foreach loop in my code where every iteration of the code requires a query of the API. Is there a way to code in the limit so that the foreach will only query a certain number of times within a set time limit so I do not reach the API's query limit? Or in other words, can I make my foreach loop iterate at a rate of 20 loops a second or any other number a second?

The foreach loop is below if you want to look at it but I do not believe you will need it to answer the question.

```
foreach(var item in matchlistd)
{
    var response2 = client.GetAsync($@"https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/{item.summonerName}apikeyiswhatgoesintherestofthispartoftheapi).Result;
    if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        summonerName player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<summonerName>(content2);
        accountinfo.Add(player);
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a timer instead. This isn't a job of the loop

Comment: You have already leaked your API key, make sure you regenerate it.

Comment: @phuclv I was unaware of the timer class. Will look into this.

Comment: To calculate this in a loop, you would have to know precisely how long each request took, which means you'd have to be able to guarantee that latency would never change between you and the server. Any minor difference in a single condition would mean that your loop failed. That means a loop isn't the suitable approach here.

Comment: @nlawalker yes I realized that. Went ahead and made the edit and regenerated it anyway just to be safe.

Comment: `.Result` is potentially dangerous can could lead to a dead-lock.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive` and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;` - then you can do some pretty cool stuff.

First off, we need to fix your code so that you don't have to rely on the `.Result` calls.

Let's just assume that your code is running in a method called `Main` - then you can change your code to work like this:

```
async void Main()
{
    // ...

    string BuildUrl(string summonerName) => $@"https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/{summonerName}apikeyiswhatgoesintherestofthispartoftheapi";

    foreach (var item in matchlistd)
    {
        var response2 = await client.GetAsync(BuildUrl(item.summonerName));
        if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var content2 = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            summonerName player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<summonerName>(content2);
            accountinfo.Add(player);
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Note the `async` and the two `await` keywords.

Now let's rewrite your loop to be an Rx observable. An observable is like an enumerable, but instead of producing all of the values immediately, it produces values one at a time.

```
IObservable<summonerName> query =
    /* 1 */ from item in matchlistd.ToObservable()
    /* 2 */ from response2 in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(BuildUrl(item.summonerName)))
    /* 3 */ where response2.IsSuccessStatusCode
    /* 4 */ from content2 in Observable.FromAsync(() => response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
    /* 5 */ select JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<summonerName>(content2);
```

1. turns your `matchlistd` enumerable into an observable
2. calls `client.GetAsync` and unwraps the task using the `Observable.FromAsync` to create an observable of the message response
3. filter out `response2.IsSuccessStatusCode == false`
4. calls `response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` and unwraps the task using the `Observable.FromAsync` to create an observable `string`
5. converts the `string` to `summonerName`.

Then you can do this to get all of the results and put it in your list:

```
accountinfo.AddRange(await query.ToList());
```

Now we just want to make this only produce up to 20 queries per second. Here's the modified query:

```
IObservable<summonerName> query =
    from items in matchlistd.ToObservable().Buffer(20).Zip(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)), (x, t) => x)
    from item in items
    from response2 in Observable.FromAsync(() => client.GetAsync(BuildUrl(item.summonerName)))
    where response2.IsSuccessStatusCode
    from content2 in Observable.FromAsync(() => response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())
    select JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<summonerName>(content2);
```

Note the following part:

```
    from items in matchlistd.ToObservable().Buffer(20).Zip(Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.Zero, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)), (x, t) => x)
    from item in items
```

That's the secret sauce. `.Buffer(20)` & `TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0)` are the bits you can change to customise the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Use a timer like below. You could also pass a variable for the timer interval.

```
private Timer _functionTimer; 

public void InitMatchList()
{
    _functionTimer_Tick = new Timer();
    _functionTimer_Tick.Tick += new EventHandler(_functionTimer_Tick);
    _functionTimer_Tick.Interval = 50; // in miliseconds
    _functionTimer_Tick.Start();
}

private void _functionTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response2 = client.GetAsync($@"https://na1.api.riotgames.com/lol/summoner/v4/summoners/by-name/{item.summonerName}apikeyiswhatgoesintherestofthispartoftheapi).Result;
    if (response2.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content2 = response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        summonerName player = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<summonerName>(content2);
        accountinfo.Add(player);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While a timer *may work* it's an old-school way of doing rate limiting.  It may not work if the server does not want more than 20 *conncurrent connections* per second.  Meaning if the result takes longer than the next *timed-request* you may still get a 429.  A alternative solution might look like:

```
private static readonly httpClient = new HttpClient();
public async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAPIResults(IEnuemrable<MatchList> matchLists,
  int maximumRequestsPerSecond)
{
    var requests = matchLists
      .Select(ml => new RequestStatus { MatchList = ml })
      .ToList();

    foreach (var request in requests)
    {
      var activeRequests = RequestStatus
        .Where(rs => 
          (rs.RequestedOn.HasValue && rs.RequestedOn > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1))
          || (rs.Task.HasValue && rs.Task.TaskStatus != TaskStatus.Running))
        .ToList();

      //wait for either a request to complete
      //or for a request not active within the last second to expire
      while (activeRequests > maximumRequestsPerSecond)
      {
        var lastActive = activeRequests.OrderBy(RequestedOn.Value).First();
        var waitFor = DateTime.Now - lastActive.RequestedOn.Value;

        // or maybe this to be safe
        // var waitFor = (DateTime.Now - lastActive.RequestedOn.Value)
        //   .Add(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

        await Task.Delay(waitFor);

        activeRequests = RequestStatus
          .Where(rs => 
            (rs.RequestedOn.HasValue && rs.RequestedOn > DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(-1))
            || (rs.Task.HasValue && rs.Task.TaskStatus != TaskStatus.Running))
          .ToList();
    }

      request.RequestTask = httpClient.GetStringAsync(myUrl);       
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(requests.Select(r => r.RequestTask.Value));

    // not sure about .Result here...
    return requests.Select(r => r.RequestTask.Value.Result).ToList();

    // probably safer:
    return requests.Select(r => await r.RequestTask).ToList();
}

public class RequestStatus
{
  public MatchList MatchList { get; set; }
  public DateTime? RequestedOn { get; set }
  public Task<string>? RequestTask { get; set; }
}
```

The delay could be better if instead of just waiting for a specific amount of time, there was a `Task.WhenAll()` task that popped a `CancellationToken` for the `Task.Delay()` method.

Comment: I agree this is a much better solution Erik that won't overrun the http connections!